# How can a GitLab ssh url show a non-default user?

Tags: gitlab

I have a GitLab installation, but it is installed under a different user to the default '`git`'.

On project pages, users are instructed to use the following URL for ssh:

```
git@host:user/project.git
```

How do I change this to show the new username?

Answer (score 0):

Try and [modify/uncomment the lines regarding ssh use in `gitlab.yml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/f055bad5135c8c3934daf16f8d9400f9a23b8960/config/gitlab.yml.example#L31-L32)

```rb
# Uncomment and customize if you can't use the default user to run GitLab (default: 'git')
# user: git
```

The initializer is supposed to use that setting when computing the ssh url for repos.
See "[`config/initializers/1_settings.rb#L12-L18`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/f055bad5135c8c3934daf16f8d9400f9a23b8960/config/initializers/1_settings.rb#L12-L18)"

```rb
def build_gitlab_shell_ssh_path_prefix
  if gitlab_shell.ssh_port != 22
    "ssh://#{gitlab_shell.ssh_user}@#{gitlab_shell.ssh_host}:#{gitlab_shell.ssh_port}/"
  else
    "#{gitlab_shell.ssh_user}@#{gitlab_shell.ssh_host}:"
  end
end
```